# How to perform math in powershell or to be more precise, from a.CSV file

Tags: windows, powershell, server, hard-drive

So I'm trying to get the values of my HDD into a CSV with either of the following functions:

This one:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select Used,Free,Name,Root | Export-CSV -path "C:\Temp\Output $env:computername\Harddisk $env:computername.csv" -delim ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

Or this one:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 10000| Out-File -Append "C:\Temp\Output $env:computername\Harddisk2 $env:computername.csv" -Encoding UTF8}
```

The output of method 1 is in bytes so I will have to perform math on it (divided by 1073741824 seems to get the correct answer) but don't know how.

The output of method 2 is in GBytes (what I want) but it only outputs it into 1 column.

Can anyone tell me how I need to perform math on the 1st or how to put a `-delimiter ";"` on the 2nd?

Comment: Powershell math isn't much different from any other math. Type `get-help about_Operators` in Powershell command prompt and look for arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your number 1.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select Name, Root, @{n="Used in GB";e={[math]::Round($_.Used/1GB,2)}}, @{n="Free in GB";e={[math]::Round($_.Free/1GB,2)}} | Export-CSV -path "C:\Temp\test1.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks! 
That was exactly what we were looking for and it works like a charm, I can see what I was doing wrong now too so a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to use if you want to have a "Total" column as well besides the "Used" and "Free" columns.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem | select Name, Root, @{n="Used in GB";e={"{0:N2}" -f  ($_.used/1GB)}},   @{n="Free in GB";e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Free/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Total in GB' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f (($_.used + $_.Free)/1GB)}} | Export-CSV -path "C:\Temp\Output $env:computername\Harddisk $env:computername 2.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```